# Angular Navigation from outside browser directly into specific page

Tags: angular

I want to create alerts for my angular application so that I can send emails including a specific link to users. So when users using an email client, I.E. Outlook receive said alert they can click the link and get directed to a specific page where they're required to take specific action to okay/update a record.

The problem I'm seeing now is if the browser is open and the user is already in the application it will navigate to the page, but if the browser isn't open it's only taking the user as far as the initial page you see when you login.

With this issue I'm not even sure where to begin since I'm not sure if this might be a particular technical constraint around sessions or if its possible if the application should be using sso to seamless login with entitlements once the application is open.

Comment: You're explicitly routing to the "after login page" somewhere in your business logic

Comment: So my assumption was is this is happening as a result of defined routes in our app-routing.module.ts file where we have path: '' and path: '**' set to redirect to the "after login page". 

The one issue is the direct link navigation seems to work when the application is already open but doesn't when the browser is closed. So I don't know if this is possible a technical constraint with how the route is rendered when the application isn't open.